# Display number of values over a certain percentage Java

Tags: java, arrays

I need to write a Java program using a bi-dimensional array that stores marks achieved by 40 students in 8 subjects, finds the average and also finds the occurrences in which a distinction was obtained (a mark over 70%). 
**The program works fine except for the last requirement**. Right now it's counting all marks **if one or more** are over 70% (therefore the result is always 8).
I guess I am confused on how to get a count of the marks **above 70% only**. Sample code is fine but please also try to explain what I am doing wrong... 
Thank you! :)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class db {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Variables
        double mark = 0, average = 0, sum = 0, counter = 0, achievement = 0, percentage = 0, counterpercentage = 0;

        double[][] marksTable = new double[40][8];
        //New Scanner object
        Scanner fromKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int studentNo = 0; studentNo < 40; studentNo++) {
            System.out.println("Enter marks for student no" + studentNo);
            sum = 0;
            counter = 0;

            for (int moduleNo = 0; moduleNo < 8; moduleNo++) {
                System.out.println("Mark for student " + studentNo + " for module no " + moduleNo + ":");
                //Read value into variable mark
                mark = fromKeyboard.nextDouble();
                // Write mark into array
                marksTable[studentNo][moduleNo] = mark;
                //Calculations
                sum = sum + mark;
                counter = counter + 1;
            }
            percentage = mark;
            average = sum / counter;
            counterpercentage = counter;
            //Display array
            for (int moduleNo = 0; moduleNo < 8; moduleNo++) {
                System.out.println("Average for student " + studentNo + " for module no " + moduleNo + " is: " + average);
                break;
            }
            if (percentage >= 70) {
                System.out.println(" The number of high marks achieved for this student are: " + counterpercentage);
            }
            if (percentage < 70) {
                System.out.println("No high marks obtained");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class db
{
    public static void main (String []args)
    {
    //Variables
    double mark=0, average=0, sum=0, counter=0, achievement=0, percentage=0, counterpercentage=0;

    double[][] marksTable = new double[40][8];
    //New Scanner object
    Scanner fromKeyboard=new Scanner (System.in);

for (int studentNo = 0; studentNo < 40; studentNo++)
{
     System.out.println("Enter marks for student no" +studentNo);
     sum =0 ;
     counter = 0;

for (int moduleNo = 0; moduleNo < 8; moduleNo++)
{
     System.out.println("Mark for student "+studentNo+" for module no      "+moduleNo+":");
     //Read value into variable mark
     mark = fromKeyboard.nextDouble();
     // Write mark into array
     marksTable[studentNo][moduleNo] = mark;
     //Calculations
     sum=sum+mark;
     counter=counter+1;
     if(mark >= 70) {  //***Changed***//
       counterpercentage++;
     }
}
average=sum/counter;
//Display array
for (int moduleNo = 0; moduleNo < 8; moduleNo++)
{
      System.out.println("Average for student "+studentNo+" for module no "+moduleNo+" is: "+average);
     break;
}
    if (counterpercentage >=0)  //***Changed***//
    {
        System.out.println("The number of high marks achieved for this student are: "+ counterpercentage);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("No high marks obtained");
    }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of this statement:

`percentage = mark;`

It assigns the value of `mark` to percentage, what we need to do here is to calculate the percentage, which would be total marks divided by max marks e.g.

`percentage = (sum/(100.0 * marksTable[studentNo].length))*100; //(Assuming 100 as max marks for eah module)`